# AUCTeX beamer class does not auto-insert section label

Tags: emacs, auctex, reftex

I am now using `AUCTeX 11.89.1` on emacs. When I start a `beamer` class document, the label is not automatically added after using `C-c C-s` to start a new section. I have to use `C-c C-(` to add the label afterwards. If I use `C-c C-e` to insert some environment (e.g., equation), the label is added automatically.

This does not happen in the usual `article` class, in which labels are automatically added. I have the following in my `.emacs` file,

```
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'reftex-mode)
```

Do I need anything else to make it work in beamer?

P.S.,
I always use `C-u C-c C-n` to make sure that the current documentclass is recognized first.

Comment: Does it help if you add `(setq LaTeX-beamer-section-labels-flag t)` to your `.emacs` and try it again?

Comment: @ArashEsbati It works! But why this different setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some AUCTeX styles can be customized, viz.:

- amsmath.el
- beamer.el
- biblatex.el
- comment.el
- csquotes.el
- emp.el
- fontspec.el
- graphicx.el

beamer.el uses`LaTeX-beamer-section-labels-flag` which defaults to `nil`:

> LaTeX-beamer-section-labels-flag is a variable defined in
>   ‘tex-style.el’.
>   Its value is nil
>
> Documentation:
>   If non-nil section labels are added

If you set this variable to `t`, AUCTeX (or RefTeX) will ask you for a label when you insert a sectioning command with `C-c C-s`.  You can set this variable in your `.emacs` with

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-beamer-section-labels-flag t)
```

or use customize with `M-x customize-group RET LaTeX-style RET`.

The relevant code in beamer.el is:

```lisp
(unless LaTeX-beamer-section-labels-flag
  (make-local-variable 'LaTeX-section-hook)
  (setq LaTeX-section-hook
    '(LaTeX-section-heading
      LaTeX-section-title
      LaTeX-section-section)))
```

where `LaTeX-section-label` is omitted.